# pytest in mingw64 cannot parse path to individual test

Tags: python, pytest, msys2

I'm running msys2 on Windows 10. I've put a test file `test-windows.py` in directory `tests`,

```
def func(x):
    return x + 1

def test1():
    assert func(3) == 5

def test2():
    assert func(3) == 4
```

When I start up the shell Mingw64 provided by msys2 and attempt to use `pytest` to run an individual test, i.e.

```
pytest test-windows.py::test2
```

I get a successful test, as expected,

```
======================================= test session starts =======================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.9.16, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: C:\Users\rdprice\Apps\msys64\home\rdprice\working\tmp\tests
collected 1 item

test-windows.py .                                                                            [100%]

======================================== 1 passed in 0.02s ========================================
```

However, when I run `pytest` from one directory higher,

```
cd ..
pytest tests/test-windows.py::test2
```

I get this

```
======================================= test session starts =======================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.9.16, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: C:\Users\rdprice\Apps\msys64\home\rdprice\working\tmp
collected 0 items

====================================== no tests ran in 0.00s ======================================
ERROR: file or directory not found: tests\test-windows.py;test2
```

The double colon `::` is replaced by a single semicolon `;`, and `pytest` can't collect the test. Replacing the `/` with `\\` does not help.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried quoting the path, in case this is an Msys shell quirk? `pytest 'tests/test-windows.py::test2'`

Comment: @AKX Quoting the path doesn't help. Same results.